# Is there a way to map a low resolution false color imaging to a high resolution photographic image?

Tags: python, imaging

I have a very high resolution photographic image with some objects in it, along with a false color scan of it, but at a lower resolution. I know that I can upscale the scan image as it is, but is there a way to instead recolor the photographic image based on the false colors of the scan?

I'm already familiar with OpenCV, and somewhat with TensorFlow, in case they might help

*Reposted after editting the title to better match guidelines, hopefully*

Comment: I don't understand: you have a high resolution image, and a low-resolution false-color version of the same image?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Why not simply use your high resolution version for whatever purpose you might have?

Comment: I need the false-color information of the scan image. I can upscale and use it as is, but if I can map the colors over the appropriate object on the HR real image, it should be visually more appealing

Comment: This might give you some ideas... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32497133/2836621

Comment: It's close to what I want to do, but it's still just an upscale and superposing them together. I'm trying to actually replace the HR image's colors instead, so that the scan itself seems high resolution as well